# Interact with API (Make a post request with test parameters to a URL)

Tags: php, laravel, api

I want to create an invoice after a payment using this API "https://invoicexpress.com/api/invoices/create" using test values for now using Guzzle. Im a beginner with API´s and Im not understanding the process.

In that documentation link says that to create a new invocie is necessary to make a POST request to the following URL "https://{account-name}.app.invoicexpress.com/invoices.xml" with the XML data of the new invoice on the request body.

Im not understanding that part of how to send a POST request to that url with the necessary parameters, do you know how that can be done?

I have a route and method for when a button to generate an invoice is clicked:

```
Route::get('/generateInvoice', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@generateInvoice',
    'as'   => 'payment.generateInvoice'
]);
```

And the method for the route:

```
public function generateInvoice(){
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('POS', 'https://accountname.invoicexpress.com/invoices.xml');
        dd($response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this for a synchro call...

```
public function generateInvoice(){
        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->post('https://accountname.invoicexpress.com/invoices.xml');
        dd($response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, like that it appears "cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:accountname.invoicexpress.com (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)". Instead of accountame is the correct account name.

Comment: With "$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://accountname.app.invoicexpress.com/invoices.xml', [
            'api_key' => '...',
            'body' => 'raw data'
        ]);" appears "Client error: `POST https://accountname.invoicexpress.com/invoices.xml` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: Invalid API key". BUt the api passed in the array is correct.

Comment: I would be tempted to use the JSON api... https://developers.invoicexpress.com/docs/versions/2.0.0 ... Looks like you should imbed the api_key in the XML itself...

Comment: Thanks, do you know what is necessary to change in"        $response = $client->request('POS', 'https://accountname.invoicexpress.com/invoices.xml');" to the json version?